Pre-open and post-close hooks for remote tunnel connections
Currently i am building a vscode extension on top of the remote tunnel extension.
With this extension you can create vscode tunnels to the servers of our IaaS platform so that you can access and change the code of your project within VS Code.
On our platform, there are cheaper servers which are called on-demand workspaces. These workspaces shuts down after 60 minutes of no usage.
The result of this is, that after reopening VS Code after 60 minutes or more, the tunnel connection cant be established, because the server is shut down.
To solve this problem i am currently looking for a workaround to send an URL request to our services to start this workspace when opening VS Code so that the tunnel connection can be established.
It seems that the tunnel connection must be established before any extension will be activated. Even with the "*" activation the extension wont be activated before the tunnel connection is established.
Additionally, i tried to mark our extension as an UI extension in our extension manifest (package.json) in the field extensionKindto ensure that our extension is executed in the local extension host. It seems even if the extension is executed locally, it wont be activated before the tunnel connection was successful.
This is the extensionhost log when trying to connect to a shut down server:
2024-06-16 17:30:59.395 [info] Extension host with pid 55036 exiting with code 0
2024-06-16 17:31:00.671 [info] Extension host with pid 55504 started
2024-06-16 17:31:00.671 [info] Skipping acquiring lock for /home/jan-david/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/c3d95f04922cc1e3717ddf5991976dcf.
2024-06-16 17:31:00.671 [info] $getCanonicalURI invoked for authority (tunnel)
2024-06-16 17:31:00.674 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode.remote-server, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onResolveRemoteAuthority:tunnel'
2024-06-16 17:31:00.710 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][0ms] activating remote resolvers tunnel+vscode-extension-12
2024-06-16 17:31:00.710 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][0ms] activating resolver for tunnel+vscode-extension-12...
2024-06-16 17:31:00.710 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][0ms] invoking final resolve()...
2024-06-16 17:31:01.223 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.github-authentication, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onAuthenticationRequest:github'
2024-06-16 17:31:01.711 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][1001ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:31:02.722 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][2012ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:31:03.723 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][3013ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:31:04.723 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][4013ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:31:05.723 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][5013ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:31:06.724 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][6014ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:31:06.950 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][6240ms] setting tunnel factory...
2024-06-16 17:31:06.950 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,1)][6240ms] returned 127.0.0.1:37141
2024-06-16 17:31:37.004 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,2)][1ms] activating remote resolvers tunnel+vscode-extension-12
2024-06-16 17:31:37.004 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,2)][1ms] activating resolver for tunnel+vscode-extension-12...
2024-06-16 17:31:37.004 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,2)][1ms] invoking final resolve()...
2024-06-16 17:31:38.005 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,2)][1002ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:31:38.284 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,2)][1281ms] setting tunnel factory...
2024-06-16 17:31:38.284 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,2)][1281ms] returned 127.0.0.1:45337
2024-06-16 17:32:08.326 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,3)][0ms] activating remote resolvers tunnel+vscode-extension-12
2024-06-16 17:32:08.326 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,3)][0ms] activating resolver for tunnel+vscode-extension-12...
2024-06-16 17:32:08.326 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,3)][0ms] invoking final resolve()...
2024-06-16 17:32:09.327 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,3)][1001ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:32:09.620 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,3)][1294ms] setting tunnel factory...
2024-06-16 17:32:09.620 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,3)][1294ms] returned 127.0.0.1:46481
2024-06-16 17:32:39.669 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,4)][0ms] activating remote resolvers tunnel+vscode-extension-12
2024-06-16 17:32:39.669 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,4)][0ms] activating resolver for tunnel+vscode-extension-12...
2024-06-16 17:32:39.669 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,4)][0ms] invoking final resolve()...
2024-06-16 17:32:40.670 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,4)][1001ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:32:41.162 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,4)][1493ms] setting tunnel factory...
2024-06-16 17:32:41.163 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,4)][1494ms] returned 127.0.0.1:37019
2024-06-16 17:33:11.209 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,5)][0ms] activating remote resolvers tunnel+vscode-extension-12
2024-06-16 17:33:11.209 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,5)][0ms] activating resolver for tunnel+vscode-extension-12...
2024-06-16 17:33:11.210 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,5)][1ms] invoking final resolve()...
2024-06-16 17:33:12.211 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,5)][1002ms] waiting...
2024-06-16 17:33:12.562 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,5)][1353ms] setting tunnel factory...
2024-06-16 17:33:12.563 [info] [resolveAuthority(tunnel,5)][1354ms] returned 127.0.0.1:35775
2024-06-16 17:33:42.899 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension johnpapa.vscode-peacock, startup: true, activationEvent: '*'
2024-06-16 17:33:42.904 [error] CodeExpectedError: ENOPRO: No file system provider found for resource 'vscode-remote://tunnel%2Bvscode-extension-12/home/user/app'
    at s.j (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:658:14838)
    at async s.exists (vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:658:17045)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1716:2988
2024-06-16 17:33:42.904 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode.remote-explorer, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onCommand:remote-internal.setActiveFolders'
2024-06-16 17:33:43.002 [info] Eager extensions activated
2024-06-16 17:33:43.010 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished'
2024-06-16 17:33:43.049 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished'
2024-06-16 17:33:43.062 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension PKief.material-icon-theme, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished'
2024-06-16 17:33:43.074 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onCommand:remote-internal.getActiveSshRemote'
2024-06-16 17:33:43.094 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.microsoft-authentication, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onAuthenticationRequest:microsoft'
2024-06-16 17:34:14.975 [error] Error: Timeout connecting to relay
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/jan-david/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.remote-server-1.5.2/dist/node/extension.js:2:925445)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Does someone has an idea how i can solve this specific issue with remote tunnels?
